# Confused on a simple for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, for-loop

OK this is a major edit. I thought I could get there by giving an example of similar simple code, but it is not helping.

I have a working function which displays a Google map, then places markers with info windows. This all works fine. Then I decided I wanted to slightly delay the dropping of the markers so instead of all dropping at once they drop pause for xx milliseconds drop the next. I cannot get this to work and the primary source of my confusion is I seem to be confused on the way a for loop is working in JavaScript.

I was using setTimeout, couldn't get this working, realized my confusion has nothing to do with the setTimeout, so I pulled it and replaced it with an alert and I get the same behavior. I am not looking for someone to write my code, I just don't understand what I'm missing here.

I would expect in a for loop is this behavior...

For
do something
do something else
do another thing
next

It appears by what I am seeing I get this behavior...

For
do something
do something else (and do it for each loop through code)
do another thing
next

So here is the code:

```
    function delaydropmarkers()
    {
        alert("delaydropmarkers");
    }

    function marker(location) 
    {

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.5, -98.35);
        var mapOptions = 
        {
            zoom: 5,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < location.length; i++) 
        {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[i][1], location[i][2]),
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                map: map
            }
            );

            delaydropmarkers();

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) 
            {
                return function () 
                {
                    infowindow.setContent(location[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            }
            )(marker, i));

        }

    }
```

So I call the marker function which should create a marker, go to the delaydropmarkers function (it just has an alert in it right now) and then add the listener. I get all markers going at once still. I'll apologize in advance I know this is something I already feel stupid about, but I am just not seeing the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK Camus, thanks for the reply... this did not work, it wrote all the cars, then four more "undefined" lines after 2 sec

Comment: Classic "setTimeout in a loop" problem. Not sure which of the [many duplicates](http://www.google.de/search?q=stackoverflow+javascript+settimeout+loop) to link…

Answer (score 1):

First mistake is using W3Schools. http://ryanblunden.com/please-dont-use-w3schools

Make it into its own function that you can recursively call when you want:

```
function showCars(cars, index) {
    index = index || 0;
    if (index < cars.length) {
        console.log(cars[index]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            showCars(cars, ++index);
        }, 2000);
    }
}

var my_cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
showCars(my_cars);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UcWTH/4/

The reason I am using `console.log` and not `document.write` as you have it in your code, is because `document.write` should **only** be used when the page is being rendered, not after. Luckily, that is true in your case. Unfortunately, `setTimeout` negates that.

Using `setTimeout` means that the code you provide for the first parameter will be executed **asynchronously** at X milliseconds later. By that time, if you used `setTimeout` properly, your page will be rendered and you will be overwriting the document. So like I said, since `setTimeout` is asynchronous, it **doesn't actually hold up/pause/stop Javascript processing**. I think that's the source of your confusion. You want it to "delay" for 2 seconds, but if you truly wanted to do that, you would freeze the browser for 2 seconds. `setTimeout` lets you do it without freezing the browser. But you can't use it in the normal way you would think...and that's why my code above isn't a normal `for` loop.

Comment: +1 for saying not to use W3Schools, -1 for not 'pausing' 2 seconds

Comment: @AlanFoster My fault. I was working on the recursion and forgot the pausing. I edited. I knew I was forgetting something

Comment: You're not using document.write either :) (Which is probably a good thing actually...)

Comment: @AlanFoster Another thing I forgot to explain. Since it won't be possible when using `setTimeout`

Comment: I think I'll get there based on the responses and will mark as the asnwer what does get me there, but I still do not understand what I am missing. I know that sounds stupid. What I mean is I expect this kind of structure: FOR (do something) next. BUt it looks like I am getting FOR (do this (loop all at once) then do this) [[NEXT SHOULD BE HERE BUT IT DOESN'T ACT THIS WAY]] exit loop. That is the source of my confusion. I hope this makes sense. I can probably get this working now, but I really don't see how the hell this is working

Comment: @jsteffler I updated my answer. Re-read it and let me know if it helps or if you need more explaining

Comment: @Ian OK... thanks. I think I get that... I think. I have to look at the "real code", what I posted was just to understand the for loop confusion, which I am still not there on. Your explanation of what is happening, generally, with setTimeout is spot on and I am crystal on that now. So this still leaves the for next question. So I think I need some sample code to look at eg: javascript looping through a set of records which I can find on my own. I think the reality is the answer is there, I'm simply not seeing it because I got confused on how setTimeout works. Thanks for your replies

Comment: @Ian, I did a major edit to my post after more testing, please take a look, thanks